# Legacy database reporting

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a customer who has an old database that needs updating.  It’s an Access 97 database (I know, I know…), but they currently access the data using a program called CD Viewer and they reference a .CCD file.  I had to install Office XP to open the Access database and it doesn’t actually contain the data that they are able to view through CD Viewer.  Further investigation revealed a .REP file that is quite large, so I’m thinking the data is in there.  However, I’ve tried several different programs that are supposed to recognize a .REP file and none can open it.  Opening in notepad reveals only gobbledegook.  There is also a .DEF file which appears (when opened in notepad) to be a template of the report that users see when examining data in the CD Viewer.

I am hoping to discover what creates the .REP file so that I can find software to open it and/or access the data from it.  Google has provided a lot of possibilities but as I said, the few I’ve tried do not recognize the .REP file.  It’s also possible that I’ve found the right source of the .REP file but it’s so outdated that it’s no recognized.  So I’m hoping these clues mean something to someone else and they can narrow down the hunt for me.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like they are viewing the Acces file via some (Citrix?) viewer. There is no way to alter the Access file via this route; you will have to have the _Access mdb_ file.

Comment: I have looked into the Access mdb file, and it doesn't have the data in it.  It has SOME data in it, but appears to be just the filters that are used by the CD Viewer to pull whatever is in the .rep file.

Comment: Hum, never heard of a REP file, and it certainly not some format used nor supported by Access. Perahps you re-name the rep file and try and see if Access will open it? It possible that the extension was used just to fool you. This is a bit of a long shot, but the REP format has to be determined, and it not a access format. (however, make a copy of the REP file, and rename the extension to mdb - see if it opens. You simply at the end of the day have to determine what file format that rep file is.